# Javascript - adding random numbers generated in for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, sum, addition

I'm trying to find the sum of all variables, `dieRoll` outputted in for loop after the images are displayed. Thanks in advance.

```
    var out = '';
        for(var i = 0; i < userSelect; i++){
            dieRoll = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
            out += "<img src=\"_images/die" + dieRoll + ".jpg\">";
       }
    return out;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var sum = 0;
var out = '';
for(var i = 0; i < userSelect; i++){
    dieRoll = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
    sum += dieRoll;
    out += "<img src=\"_images/die" + dieRoll + ".jpg\">";
}
```

Based on the return statement in your example, your function is currently returning just HTML text. You may wish to refactor the code so that one function returns an array of integer die rolls, another function returns the sum of the array, and another function returns the desired HTML text.